# Best convergence rate for convolutions on $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: pr.probability, ergodic-theory, markov-chains

Suppose, that we have sequence of i.i.d variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ taking values in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $d_{TV}(X_1,U) < \delta$.
How fast, in terms of $\delta$ and $n$ does the sum $X_1+\ldots+X_n$ tend towards to the uniform distribution?

I am interested in the best possible estimates, depending only on $\delta$ and $n$.

Comment: I might get back to this problem again for now you might be interested in this paper...R. Urban. Some remarks on the random walk on ﬁnite groups. Colloq Math
74, No.2 287-298, 1997.

Comment: Thanks! But I already solved this problem some time ago by an application of some fourier analysis (for big values of $n$).

Comment: Don't suppose it is something that I might be able to get my hands on and have a look at?